# Placing large figures at end of paper

Tags: publications, graphics, formatting

I have some elaborate drawings that need some space.  I think putting them "inline" would  break the flow of the (mathematics) paper.

Questions:

1. Where exactly should they go?  Just before the References? Do I have to make a section header for them, like Figures or Appendix?
2. Some of my figures will remain inline.  Do I number the figures in order of appearance, or in the order they are referenced?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a paper for a journal? Note that wherever you put them, the typesetter might put them otherwise, according to the journal's guidelines.

Comment: what does the journal style guide say?

Comment: Yes it will be submitted to journals. I'm not sure which one at the moment.  Let me phrase it this way: Assuming they will go at the end of the document, what are the standard practices?

Comment: Journals in math might be different, but the way journals in biology operate, you typically submit everything in a particular order as dictated by the journal, with figures usually coming last or in separate documents, and figure captions usually in the primary document but also last. Only during typesetting, done by the journal, are the figures actually placed anywhere in the paper.

Answer (score 5):

The journal you are submitting to might have a style guide which will tell you what to do. If not, do what you, your advisor, or a different journal style guide suggests. Your paper may get *administratively rejected* if they do not like the formatting, but they will tell you what to fix and let you submit again. In my field, all figures go at the end, one figure per page, in the order referenced, after the references and appendices when submitting. The copy editor/publisher deals with laying out the manuscript once it is accepted.

Basically, it doesn't matter, just do something reasonable.